# SplashScreen wont goto main application (ANDROID)

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Splash in Android not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997510/splash-in-android-not-working)

My splashscreen stays still. It doesn't let the main app run after. Here's the code I am using: I have three files: Splash.xml, Splash.java and SplashNew.java

```
     package com.timchecklist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Thread Timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.timchecklist.SPLASHNEW"));

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        Timer.start();
    }

}
```

SplashNew.java

```
   package com.timchecklist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class SplashNew extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    }

}
```

Splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/pic1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

AndroidManifest.xml

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.timchecklist"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TimCheckListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashNew"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any Ideas / Help ?

Ty guys

Answer (score 2):

Please change `startActivity(new Intent("com.timchecklist.SPLASHNEW"));` to `startActivity(new Intent(SplashNew.class));`

Comment: thats not the prob . the prob is it wont goto main.

Comment: SplashNew is main? You cannot go to SplashNew on your way because "com.timchecklist.SPLASHNEW" doesn't exist. I have forgotten how to create this short-cut, but I prefer this way. Just test it.

Comment: no main is: TimCheckListActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE do not make your users wait 3 seconds for a splash screen if you don't have any work to be done during that time. If there is work you must do in order for your application then do that work in the background while you are showing a splash screen. If you force your users to wait 3 seconds for no reason whenever they use your app, they will be displeased.

Here is a good [post about splashscreens](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/) with an example of a way to implement them.

But I seriously cannot stress enough if you have no good reason to make the user wait then DON'T make them wait.

**EDIT:** Also if you insist upon making your users wait for a *pointless* splash screen at the very least implement some way to check to see if the user pressed back (exited your app) during the splash, and if they did don't call startActivity(). With the way you have it now, even if the user presses back during the splash (which they will if you make them wait 3 seconds for *no reason*.) your thread is still going to call startActivity() which is going to drop your Activity on top even though the user exited by presseing the back button. The link above talks about this.